# Category select options for plugin settings

Tags: plugin-development, theme-options, settings-api

I am using Aqua page builder and I want to incorporate dropdown catagory select field for that.

```
<?php 
$my_options = array ('one' => 'My Pony','two' => 'His Pony');
echo aq_field_select('categories', $block_id, $my_options, $categories);
?>
```

I have tried `$my_options= get_categories();` But it does not work. The function was  basically

```
    function aq_field_select($field_id, $block_id, $options, $selected) {
    $options = is_array($options) ? $options : array();
    $output = '<select id="'. $block_id .'_'.$field_id.'" name="aq_blocks['.$block_id.']['.$field_id.']">';
    foreach($options as $key=>$value) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$key.'" '.selected( $selected, $key, false ).'>'.htmlspecialchars($value).'</option>';
    }
    $output .= '</select>';

    return $output;
}
```

Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for .

```
$cats = get_terms('category');
$blog_cats = array("all" => "All");
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
$blog_cats[$cat->name] = $cat->name;}
```

Then to show this

```
<?php echo aq_field_select('category', $block_id, $blog_cats, $category); ?>
```